# react-native gradual transition from background color a to b

Tags: react-native, animation

When clicking a button the color is supposed to transition gradually to another color along with the sliding animation. instead of gradually transitioning the color switches instantly. Is there any way i can get this animation to be executed slowly easing from color a to b ?

[image]

here is the code i have so far

```
const DriveMenuFooterAnimatedButton = () => {
    const {t} = useTranslation();
    const {colors} = useContext(ThemeContext);
    const buttonStyle = replaceAllStyles(style, colors);
    const scaledButtonWidth = scale(BUTTON_WIDTH);




    const opacityAnimation = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
    const translateAnimation = useRef(new Animated.Value(scaledButtonWidth * -1)).current;
    const colorAnimation = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
    const colorAnimationInterpolation =  colorAnimation.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0,300],
        outputRange: ["#00AA91", "#0A0082"]
    });


    const {setTrainDriveState, trainDriveState} = useContext(TrainStateContext);

    const restartLabel = t("drive:menu:restart");
    const pauseLabel = t("drive:menu:pause");
    const startLabel = t("drive:menu:start");

    console.log("trainDriveState", trainDriveState);


    const onPressHandler = useCallback(
        () => {
            const isPlay = trainDriveState === paused || trainDriveState === start;
            setTrainDriveState(isPlay ? play : paused);
        },[setTrainDriveState, trainDriveState]
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        let translateValue = scaledButtonWidth * -1;
        let colorValue = 0;
        if (trainDriveState === paused){
            translateValue = scaledButtonWidth;
        } else if (trainDriveState === play){
            translateValue = 0;
            colorValue = 300;
        }


        Animated.parallel([
            Animated.timing(colorAnimation,{
                toValue: colorValue,
                duration: ANIMATION_DURATION,
                delay: 0,
                useNativeDriver:false
            }),
            Animated.timing(translateAnimation, {
                toValue: translateValue ,
                delay: 0,
                duration: ANIMATION_DURATION,
                easing: Easing.inOut(Easing.ease),
                useNativeDriver:true
            })
        ]).start();

        return () => {

        };
    },[translateAnimation, trainDriveState, scaledButtonWidth, colorAnimation, opacityAnimation]);


    return (
        <Animated.View
            style={[buttonStyle["animation-container"], {backgroundColor: colorAnimationInterpolation}]}
        >
            <DigiPlanButton
                onPress={onPressHandler}
                activeOpacity={1}
                customStyle={style}
            >
                <Animated.View
                    style={[
                        buttonStyle["text-animation-container"],
                        {transform: [{translateX: translateAnimation}]}
                    ]}
                >
                    <DigiPlanText customStyle={buttonStyle["button-text"]}>{restartLabel}</DigiPlanText>
                    <DigiPlanText customStyle={buttonStyle["button-text"]}>{pauseLabel}</DigiPlanText>
                    <DigiPlanText customStyle={buttonStyle["button-text"]}>{startLabel}</DigiPlanText>
                </Animated.View>

            </DigiPlanButton>
        </Animated.View>

    );
};

const style = {
    "button-touchable": {
        width: scale(BUTTON_WIDTH),
        paddingHorizontal: 0,
        overflow: "hidden",
        backgroundColor: "transparent"
    },
    "text-animation-container": {
        display:"flex",
        flexDirection: "row",
        textAlign: "center"
    },
    "animation-container": {
        borderRadius: 4
    },
    "button-text": {
        width: "100%",
        backgroundColor: "transparent",
        fontSize: "font-size-l",
        textAlign: "center",
        color: "primary-light"
    }
};

export default DriveMenuFooterAnimatedButton;
```

Answer (score 0):

for those facing a similar problem i managed to figure out the following solution

(props to William Candillon on youtube with his slider video on youtube)

```
....

const  AnimatedButton = () => {
    const { colors } = useContext(ThemeContext);
    const mainStyle = replaceAllStyles(styles, colors);

    const {t} = useTranslation();
    const {setTrainDriveState, trainDriveState} = useContext(TrainStateContext);

    // annimation vals
    const scrollViewRef = useRef();
    const x = useValue(0);
    const onScroll = onScrollEvent({ x });
    const backgroundColor = interpolateColor(x,{
        inputRange: [0, BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_WIDTH * 2],
        outputRange: [ "#0A0082", "#0A0082", "#00AA91"]
    });

    // button labels
    const restartLabel = t("drive:menu:restart");
    const pauseLabel = t("drive:menu:pause");
    const startLabel = t("drive:menu:start");

    // scroll to label corresponding to trainDriveState
    useEffect(() => {
        if (scrollViewRef.current && scrollViewRef.current.getNode){
            const node = scrollViewRef.current.getNode();
            let labelPosition;
            if (node){
                if (trainDriveState === paused){
                    labelPosition = BUTTON_WIDTH * 2;
                } else if (trainDriveState === play){
                    labelPosition = BUTTON_WIDTH;
                } else if (trainDriveState === start){
                    labelPosition = 0;
                }
                node.scrollTo({x: labelPosition, animated: true});
            }
        }
    }, [scrollViewRef, trainDriveState]);

    const handlePress = useCallback(
        () => {
            const isPlay = trainDriveState === paused || trainDriveState === start;
            setTrainDriveState(isPlay ? play : paused);
        },
        [setTrainDriveState, trainDriveState],
    );


    return (
        <TouchableOpacity style={mainStyle.container} onPress={handlePress} activeOpacity={1} >
            <Animated.View style={[mainStyle.slider, {backgroundColor} ]}>
                <Animated.ScrollView
                    ref={scrollViewRef}
                    horizontal
                    snapToInterval={BUTTON_WIDTH}
                    decelerationRate="fast"
                    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                    scrollEventThrottle={1}
                    scrollToOverflowEnabled={true}
                    scrollEnabled={false}
                    // bounces={false}
                    {...{onScroll}}
                >
                    <Slide label={startLabel}/>
                    <Slide label={pauseLabel}/>
                    <Slide label={restartLabel}/>
                </Animated.ScrollView>
            </Animated.View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
};


const styles = {
    container: {
        height: BUTTON_HEIGHT,
        width: BUTTON_WIDTH
    },
    slider: {
        height: BUTTON_HEIGHT,
        width: BUTTON_WIDTH,
        borderRadius: scale(4)
    }
};


export default AnimatedButton;
```

```
...

export const BUTTON_WIDTH = scale(272);
export const BUTTON_HEIGHT = verticalScale(48);


const Slide = ({label}) => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <DigiPlanText customStyle={styles.label}>{label}</DigiPlanText>
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = {
    container: {
        borderRadius: scale(4),
        width: BUTTON_WIDTH,
        height: BUTTON_HEIGHT,
        display: "flex",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center"
    },
    label: {
        textAlign: "center",
        fontSize: "font-size-l",
        color: "primary-light"
    }
};


export default Slide;
```